# How to retrieve a message link if it contains a specific string?

Tags: discord.py

I tried doing something like this
ctx = message

`"https://discordapp.com/channels/"+ctx.guild.id+"/"+ctx.channel.id+"/"+ctx.id`
`"https://discordapp.com/channels/"+guild.id+"/"+ctx.channel.id+"/"+ctx.id`

Neither worked
If you're confused, Lets say if the message contains "hi" I want it to copy the message link and post it, so if someone clicks on the link it redirects them to that message

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def keyword(ctx, *, word: str):  # Usage: !keyword hi
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=200).flatten()  # Get last 200 messages

    for msg in messages:  # Iterate through all messages.
        if word in msg.content:
            await ctx.send(msg.jump_url)  # Send the jump link to the message containing the word.
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was stuck on that for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

```
discord.Message.jump_url
```

Reference:https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=jump_url#discord.Message.jump_url